# How could I use same python logger in different files?

Tags: python, logging

in the main.py I configure the python logger like this:

```
import func
import os.path as osp
import logging

logfile = '{}.log'.format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'))
logfile = osp.join('./res/', logfile)
FORMAT = '%(levelname)s %(filename)s(%(lineno)d): %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=FORMAT, f ilename=logfile)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

This works fine in this `main.py` file, but I still need the use the same logger in my `func.py` file which is a module imported by my `main.py`. I still need to print the log message to the screen together with the same logger file as in `main.py`. How could I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just define it and import it as a simple solution. When you import you do have access to your definitions in the other file... Just look at the imports in the code you posted.

Comment: So you mean I should define a variable `logger` in some `logger.py` file and then import this variable in other files?

Comment: Thats the idea.